# How a database index works on range queries >=, <= etc

Tags: database

I'm wondering how a database can take advantage of an index on say `foo` in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo > 10
```

In a simple equality query such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo = 10
```

The database can just use the value `10` as the key to the index, and so it's easy to check. But in the case where `foo > 10`, it seems like you would not be able to benefit from the index anymore, it would have to scan all of the records. Wondering how they actually work then, since it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index it's generally considered to be an ordered list, so for situations like `>10` it can skip directly to the spot where `10` should be and start stepping through the next entries.

This also applies to range conditions such as `BETWEEN x AND y` where it can take subsets of the index.